# Не работает интернет на ubuntu server 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

Решил поставить ubuntu 16,04 server на старый ноутбук, с горем пополам смог её установить)) так как с флешки на старый ноут он не хотела устанавливаться пришлось менять сидюк 
С ubuntu я знаком не давно так что не судите строго

Возникла проблема с подключением к интернету
в файле /etcnetwork/interfaces такие настройки

```
=========================
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp3s0 # название проверял через ifconfig -a
iface enp3s0 inet dhcp
==========================
#так же пробовал такие настройки 
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 192.168.0.77
network 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.0.1
dns-namesrvers 8.8.8.8
========================
роутер к которому подключен ноутбук имеет адрес 192.168.0.1

ping 192.168.0.1 пишет 
From 192.168.0.77 Destination Host Unreachable
ethtool enp3s0 выдает последней строчкой 
Link detected: no
```

бьюсь уже 2 дня перешарил все мануалы 
в фото вывод $ ip a; dmesg | grep enp3s0
[image: в фото ip a; dmesg | grep enp3s0]

---

**Вода**
Прошло уже много времени, я многое попробовал, даже пришлось поставить джабер  и подключиться к каналу где тусуются гуру ubuntu, они тоже пришли к выводу 
что у меня скорее всего не работает вход сетевой карты, но задачу не смотря на это решить нужно и я решил не бросать все и доделать до конца. + имхо эта  статья ещё кому ни будь понадобиться.

---

В ноуте остался интерфейс wifi, пытался прокинуть инет через него, но тут тоже замкнутый круг подскажите куда двигаться, вообщем
имеется роутер дом ру он раздает wifi только wpa2 настроек в нем кроме ввода лиц. счета и пароля от дома ру ни каких нет, даже пароль поменять нельзя или название ssid, а чтоб подключиться к wifi wpa2 из базовой версии нужна специальная утилита Supplicant, как её установить не имея интернета на данной машине не пойму. подскажите в какую строну двигаться!!! или я не прав по поводу Supplicant

Comment: После изменения настроек `ifdown` затем `ifup` выполнять не забывали?

Comment: sudo systemctl restart networking делал так

Comment: да пробовал пишет interfaces en3s0 already configured

Comment: приложите, пожалуйста, к вопросу (нажав [edit]) выдачу команды `$ ip a; dmesg | grep enp3s0`

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше предоставлять в виде текста, а не картинки: и читать удобнее, и поисковики её проиндексируют. // проблема прозрачна: *no carrier* — нет несущей. т.е. не подключен кабель. проверьте: 1. оба разъёма, 2. целостность и правильность расположения жил в кабеле, 3. другой сетевой адаптер.